# Wordpress hierarchy clarification, does post_type_archive take precedence over taxonomy-term archive?

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

Looking at the [hierarchy diagram](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) indeed the post_type archive is above the taxonomy however aren't they parallel and isn't taxonomy-term-archive more specific?

**the permalink**: `domain.com/cpt1/term1_of_ctax1/term1_of_ctax2`

**goal**: display `taxonomy-ctax2.php` or `taxonomy-ctax2-term1_of_ctax2.php` but with post that are also in `term1_of_ctax1`.

(Essentially display the list of posts that are part of *term1_of_ctax1* and *term1_of_ctax2* that has a post_type of *cpt1*)

**rewrite_rule**:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^cpt1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?ctax2=$matches[2]&ctax1=$matches[1]&post_type=cpt1&taxonomy=ctax2&term=$matches[2]','top' )
```

**the resulting** `matched query`:

```
ctax2=term1_of_ctax2
&ctax1=term1_of_ctax1
&post_type=cpt1
&taxonomy=ctax2
&term=term1_of_ctax2
```

With the matched_query including specific `taxonomy` and `term` query_vars the *template hierarchy list* from **Query monitor** does include `taxonomy-ctax2-term1_of_ctax2.php` however the actual page is rendered using the post_type `archive-cpt1.php`.

My confusion arises because in the [`template-loader.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php) "*tax*" is processed after *post_type_archive* which I believe would mean that tax template should be take precedence over post_type_archive right?

**Query monitor template results**:

**Template File**

```
archive-ctp1.php
```

**Template Hierarchy**

```
taxonomy-ctax2-term1_of_ctax2.php
taxonomy-ctax2.php
taxonomy.php
archive-cpt1.php
archive.php
index.php
```

Comment: `cpt1/term1_of_ctax1/term1_of_ctax2` is not the standard format of a taxonomy archive URL. Have you customised it in some way with your own rewrite rules? You may actually be loading the post type archive with filtered results, rather than the true taxonomy archive, which would be at something like `ctax1/term1_of_ctax1`.

Comment: hey @JacobPeattie! Yes i've updated the question with additional information.